# Flask-SqlAlchemy Filtering by time section of datetime

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am looking to filter by the time section of a datetime column in Flask-Admin using Flask-SQlAlchemy.

My attempt so far is:

```
class BaseTimeBetweenFilter(filters.TimeBetweenFilter):
    def apply(self, query, value, alias=None):
        return query.filter(cast(Doctor.datetime, Time) >= value[0],
              cast(Doctor.datetime, Time) <= value[1]).all()
```

I've got the time selector showing and if I do

```
print (value[0])
```

or

```
print (value[1])
```

it prints out the inputted times as expected. However the query is not working.

> admin-panel_1  |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>
> admin-panel_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
>
> admin-panel_1  |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>
> admin-panel_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
>
> admin-panel_1  |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> admin-panel_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
>
> admin-panel_1  |     raise value
>
> admin-panel_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
>
> admin-panel_1  |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
>
> admin-panel_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
>
> admin-panel_1  |     return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>
> admin-panel_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
>
> admin-panel_1  |     return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
>
> admin-panel_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
>
> admin-panel_1  |     return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
>
> admin-panel_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 1818, in index_view
>
> admin-panel_1  |     view_args.search, view_args.filters)
>
> admin-panel_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 975, in get_list
>
> admin-panel_1  |     count = count_query.scalar() if count_query else None
>
> admin-panel_1  | AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'scalar'

Also, I import Time and Cast from sqlalchemy, is this OK or should I be getting it from flask-sqlalchemy?

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Time, cast
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask-Admin constructs a query by joining tables, applying filters and sorting. After all this procedures it calls the query itself and gets its results.

Your `apply` method should return `sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query` instance as the one it gets as `query` argument. When you add `.all()` method this query is called and you get query result as a list. Remove `.all()` call from result value and your filter should work:

```py
class BaseTimeBetweenFilter(filters.TimeBetweenFilter):
    def apply(self, query, value, alias=None):
        return query.filter(
            cast(Doctor.datetime, Time) >= value[0],
            cast(Doctor.datetime, Time) <= value[1]
        )
```

The source of importing doesn't really matter. `flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy` instance contains the same objects as `sqlalchemy`:

```py
>>> from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
>>> db = SQLAlchemy()
>>> db.Time
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Time'>
>>> db.cast
<function cast at 0x7f60a3e89c80>
>>> from sqlalchemy import Time, cast
>>> Time
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Time'>
>>> cast
<function cast at 0x7f60a3e89c80>
>>> db.cast == cast and db.Time == Time
True
```